# Big Query External table - Query performance degrades with increased number of files in the Source URI

Tags: google-bigquery, query-optimization, parquet, external-tables

I have an external big query table created to read "Parquet" files from a GCS bucket.

The folder layout in the GCS bucket is as follows:

```
gs://mybucket/root/year=2022/model=abc/
gs://mybucket/root/year=2022/model=.../
gs://mybucket/root/year=2021/model=abc/
gs://mybucket/root/year=2021/model=.../
```

The layout is organized in such a way that it follows hive partitioning layout as explained the big query documentation. The columns "year" and "model" are seen as partition columns in the external table.

```
**External Data Configuration**

Source URI(s)- gs://mybucket/root/*

Source format - PARQUET 

Hive Partitioning Mode - CUSTOM 

Hive Partitioning Source URI Prefix - gs://mybucket/root/{year:INTEGER}/{model:STRING} 

Hive Partitioning Column(s)- year, model
```

**Problem:** When I run queries on the external table as given below, I have observed that every query runs for an initial 2-3 minutes before the actual run happens. Big Query console shows "Query pending" during this time and as soon as it turns "Query Running" the output gets displayed with minimal slot time consumption (Slot time shows in 1-2 seconds.)

```
Select * from myTable Where year = 2022 and model = 'abc'
```

The underlying file count will vary and increases for every year and model. For years with more parquet files the initial time sometimes is around 4-5 minutes.

My understanding as per the documentation is that , if the partition columns are present in the query, some sort of partition pruning happens and I expect the query to be responsive immediately as per the documentation.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-queries-gcs#partition_pruning

But the observations made by me is contrary to this. If the source URIs are restricted to 1 year, the table reads the data from one year, the query initial time (where it remains "Query pending" on console) is reduced to 1-2 minute (or even less)

```
Source URI(s)- gs://mybucket/root/year=2022/*
```

**Question:**  Is this the expected behavior ? because as volume of files increase in the GCS bucket, the query takes even longer to run (esp. the initial time, and the actual run time doesn't change much), though in the where clause we have the year and model partition columns applied.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely expected behavior.  Before partition pruning can happen objects in GCS need to be listed which is likely where the time is being taken.    We are working on improvements in this area.  The fact that slot time is so low is a good indicator that pruning   is in fact happening (since most files are not being read there isn't a lot of slot time to consume).